# WSO2 APIM URL pattern mediation script

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am using WSO2 APIM v2.0.0 and working through a POC.

I managed to understand and use message mediation policies on in/out/fault flows. This mediation policy applies to the entire API.

But I would like to use a mediation script for various URL pattern defined under the same API.
[image]

I found the following in the gateway (Carbon) under resources. Are you able to guide me with a documentation of implementing this please.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is the best idea. I'd suggest rather to use a mediation sequence, where based on the resource path ( $axis:REST_URL_POSTFIX ) you could invoke other sequences.

Comment: Cheers, thanks. Will try implementing.

Comment: Can you point me to a documentation or few examples where its described how to apply mediation sequence per URL pattern / resource please

Answer (score 3):

You can't engage mediation sequences per URL pattern. But you can for in sequence and out sequence separately.

In your case, you can read request path within a mediation sequence like below and implement your logic depending on that.

```
<property name="ApiName" scope="transport" expression="$ctx:REST_SUB_REQUEST_PATH"/>
```

For more details, read [this blog post](http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2016/08/wso2-api-manager-how-to-retrieve.html).

Comment: Thanks. This should get me cracking.

Comment: Additionally, this is a nice doc how to assign a mediation flow to the input https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+Mediation+Extensions